# How to use a library in my struct

Tags: c++

```
struct date
{
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
  void input()
  {
      std::cin>>day>>month>>year;
  }
};

#include<iostream>

main()
{
  date d1;
  d1.input();
}
```

`cin` is not working unless iostream is included. But we cannot declare a struct as global unless we define it before main function.

How can I use library functions in my struct.

Comment: Unrelated to CodeBlock which is an IDE.

Comment: What is the issue to move `#include<iostream>` before the class definition ?

Comment: *"we cannot declare a `struct` as global"* - you can declare a `struct` as global even *after* the `main` function (see forward declarations). Apart from that, the correct order in your case would be 1. `#include<iostream>` 2. the `date` declaration 3. your `main` function

Comment: You wouldn't want to constrain input to be only from `std::cin`, so write a proper `operator>>(std::ostream&, date&)` and use `#include <iosfwd>` to ensure the type is defined.  Or just move the definition of `input()` away from the declaration, after `std::cin` is defined.

Answer (score 5):

Put the `#include <iostream>` at the top. This should fix it.

Normally includes are done at the very beginning anyway. This has nothing to do with codeblocks, only c++.